# lighttpd folder/site specific config files

Tags: virtualhost, lighttpd, configuration

I've been researching what I'm sure is a very simple task. Coming from .htaccess to lighttpd.conf, I'm sure I am still missing some important concepts.

I am using lighttpd for a number of virtual hosts, and I would like to set some specific settings for some of the websites. Also, I would want to set folder specific settings for folders that have a different default page and for protected folders.

I guess my main questions is:
How are separate website/folder configurations possible with lighttpd?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you need to accomplish but there are ways to get it done. It will need to be included in your main configuration and a server restart is required to load any modifications as DerfK mentioned.

But it is possible to do the things that you want using some clever regular expressions and/or using lua scripts with **mod_magnet**.

If you need to limit access to certain protected folders, you can use **mod_auth** and/or **mod_access** instead.

However, something like .htaccess files in each folder, will not work very well for lighty.

Comment: For now, just basic things like a custom default page for that folder, and I will look into the mod_access/mod_auth. Those are still run from the main lighttpd.conf though, huh?

Comment: everything runs from the main config. you should be able to specify custom default pages if you wrap them around individual host settings.

Comment: But I would have to specify them in the main config file and restart the server, correct?  Where can I find directions on how to wrap site specific settings in the main config?

Comment: Yes, correct. Refer to the lighttpd wiki. There are examples for doing all kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer is [no](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Do-you-support-htaccess-files).

The unofficial answer is that [there are hacks](http://diaryproducts.net/about/web_servers/lighttpd/htaccess_lighttpd) that look for lighttpd configuration snippits throughout the web tree and use lighttpd's `include_shell` statement to run a command when the server starts that finds them all and adds them to the main configuration, but 1) they're attached to the main configuration so a malicious user can mess with the main configuration and 2) they're only read when the server starts, changing one requires restarting the server.